# Unable to transfer large files over Wi-Fi (>10GB)

Tags: windows, networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, adapter

I am coming here for help with my issue, I cannot transfer large files over WiFi from my Windows 10 machine to my Ubuntu Server running Plex. I am using SMB on my Ubuntu Server to transfer files from Windows. My desktop PC is located on the other side of the house of the router, so it is pretty difficult to run a wire directly to it, hence why I am using Wi-Fi. I am using a Netgear AC Wifi network adapter, which is talking to a Ubiquiti AC access point with direct line-of-sight about 20-30ft away, and the AP is mounted on the ceiling. I haven't transferred large files over Wi-Fi before, so I'm not sure if this is a Wi-Fi issue or a Windows issue... Any help would be great, thanks.

More info: Sometimes the progress bar will get 1/3 or 1/2 way through transferring.. then an error pops up saying it is unable to transfer. But most times at the beginning of the transfer while "Calculating" the time it will take, it never starts transferring.

Comment: What is happening?  Right click on the Network Icon, Adapters and double click on the Wi-Fi icon.  You should see bytes being transferred.  Start the transfer and then what happens at 10 GB?

Comment: Does the destination file system happen to be [FAT32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT32)? FAT32 has a maximum file size of less than 4GiB, which could explain a ≥10GB transfer failing ⅓ (12.88GiB file) to ½ (8.59GiB file) of the way through.

Comment: I can transfer files (machines) 50 GB in size Windows to Windows using Wireless and the transfer completes, so it is not likely a Windows issue and (assuming you have good wireless), not likely wireless either

Comment: @John, I am getting an error, I am unable to provide an exact error code at this time however.

Comment: @Deltik I am using EXFAT as my file system on the Ubuntu Server. I wanted to use a file system that Windows would recognize if I ever had to plug these drives into a Windows box.

Comment: To help narrow down the error, can you try (1) same transfer to another Windows machine and (2) different machine to the same Ubuntu machine?

Comment: Unfortunately I could never find an answer to this problem. Fortunately however, I was able to find a different way to transfer files. I am now using WinSCP instead of smb. No errors, no speed issues, it just works. Thank you everyone for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

In similar cases, the limitation has been on trying to "push" a file *to* a machine, but the converse, *requesting* the file succeeds.

Workaround:

- Create a shared directory on the Windows PC machine.
- Set security appropriately (for testing, you can allow full control for all users, but for security, make it more restrictive after getting this to work).
- Put the files to be transferred in the Windows shred folder.
- Connect from the Ubuntu server (using UNC path specification, rather than trying to search teh network, is more reliable) and download a copy of the file. An advantage of copying, rather than moving, the file is that ownership should belong to the Ubuntu user.

Hopefully, this will help... (Please let me know if that is not the case, and I'll remove this answer.)